# How to access keycloak's "/realm/account" page with access token only

Tags: authentication, keycloak, bearer-token, openid-connect

I developed desktop application which uses Keycloak (oidc) for user authentication. Application uses embedded browser for user authentication so it doesn't have access to user's credentials. When user authenticates, authentication token is securely stored on local machine. Refresh token is used for token renewal so users don't have to authenticate every time application starts.

I want to enable users to view account page inside embedded browser that links to  https://keycloakserver/auth/realms/myrealm/account/, preferably without entering credentials.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: did you solve that in your application?

Comment: Sorry, no. There were tasks with greater priority so this was postponed indefinitely.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am very interested as I am trying to do the same thing